# MySQL Conditional Select Replace Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have found myself in need of replacing certain returned results from a MySQL Select Query. I have the following table and data (simplified for example purposes)

```
uid  |  duration |  range |     unique |    stamp
-----------------------------------------------------------------
23   |  d    |  43    |     1      |    1
24   |  d    |  65    |     0      |    2
25   |  d    |  76    |     0      |    3
26   |  d    |  33    |     0      |    4
27   |  d    |  44    |     1      |    5
28   |  d    |  43    |     1      |    6
29   |  d    |  67    |     0      |    7
30   |  d    |  88    |     0      |    8
31   |  d    |  63    |     0      |    9
```

The `stamp` column is what I want to do the replace on. Rather than a simple text replace, I was wondering if its possible to run some sort of user defined function on the column and replace it dynamically.

For example If the data returned in the stamp column is a 1, I would like it to replace it with today's timestamp, if it is a 2 then yesterdays timestamp, a 3, the day before yesterdays and so on and so forth.

So my question is, is it possible to point `REPLACE` to a function that processes the value and then returns what to replace it with. Or if not, is there another way to accomplish this.

I could obviously post process the returned data in PHP and make the changes, but with millions of records returned, it will increase the load time considerably.

**EDIT TO MAKE THINGS A BIT CLEARER:** I want to replace the stamp column in the data returned from a SELECT Query, I am not storing the data anywhere, or replacing the data in the table. The table will remain unchanged.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really want to replace it by timestamp, timestamp - 1, timestamp -3 etc ... or it is just an example ?

Comment: Yes that is my requirement in this instance, but I can see myself wanting to do more complex/conditional replaces in the future also.

Comment: Your current `stamp` column is either `INT` or `VARCHAR`/`CHAR` data type. Are you going to change data type (i.e. to `DATETIME`/`DATE` or similar)?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo No there is no need to change the data type, unless that's a requirement to get the result I want..

Comment: @superphonic but then, how you want to store _'day before yesterday'_ (02 Sep for today)?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Looks like I may not have been clear in my question. I want to do the replace in a select query, I am then doing stuff with the result in php, populating a graph etc... I am not storing the returned results anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely possible:

```
UPDATE stamps
SET stamp = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL stamp - 1 DAY;
```

**[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc1ed/1)**. Note that you have to decrement the stamp value by 1 to "minus 0 days" for a stamp of `1`. If you remove the `- 1`, you'll end up storing yesterday's date for `stamp` values of `1`.

**UPDATE** to answer your question about doing it on `SELECT`:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL stamp - 1 DAY
FROM stamps;
```

**[Updated Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbed2d/3)**

Comment: How would I do this on a select query?

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Bit cheeky of me, but say I wanted '1' to be last Sundays timestamp, and then '2' be the Sunday before that etc... going back in weeks rather than days?

Comment: I figured out how to do it from sunday `SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) +1 DAY) - INTERVAL stamp - 1 WEEK
FROM stamps;`

Comment: Nice! Sorry, got distracted by "work". Glad we worked out the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the case statement of mysql

CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to retrieve the results, use the following:

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL stamp -1 DAY FROM myTable
```